# Javascript event.target cannot find children. NodeList and HTMLChildren is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a menu with submenu with Vanilla JavaScript

HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>Sub menu item 1</li>
         <li>
              <ul>
                 <li>Sub menu of a submenu item 1</li>
                 <li>Sub menu of a submenu item 2</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>Sub menu item 1</li>
         <li>Sub menu item 2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript looks like:

```
   var clickHandler = function(event){
      
        event.preventDefault();
         
        if(event.target.tagName != 'LI') return;

        //when I click on the **li** which has a **ul**, it returns empty node list
        console.log(event.target.querySelectorAll('ul')); //returns empty NodeList
    } 

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
    {
        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
        //console.log(menu)
        menu.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
    });
```

**Why is does event.target.querySelectorAll('ul') returns empty nodelist**

Please note, the reason I put click event on **#menu** instead of **#menu > li** is because I don't want to use loop to attach event handlers in each LI

To be precise,
When any **li** is clicked I want to check if it has a submenu (**ul**) , if it does then I will add a class 'open' to the clicked 'li'.
I don't care where the **li** is located, I only want to know if it contains a **ul**.

In JQuery it should be something like .find('ul');

Comment: are you trying to get the UL of the sublist ?

Comment: Because the click event happens on the sub-item <li>, not on the parent.

Comment: console.log(event.target.parentNode);

Comment: When #menu > li is clicked, I want to check if it has a ul

Comment: Then `if(event.target.matches("#menu>li>ul, #menu>li>ul *"))` will do that, but your question is not asking for this currently.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you made this so complex. If it's required because of any reason, let us know.

```
let allLi = document.querySelectorAll("ul:not(#menu) li");
[...allLi].forEach(li => {
 li.addEventListener("click", callThisFunction) 
});

function callThisFunction() {
  console.log(event.target.innerText)
}
```

EDIT:
After the explanation in the comment down below, I made the following changes:

```
let allLi = document.querySelectorAll("li");
[...allLi].forEach(li => {
 let method = li.querySelector("ul") ? function1 : function2;
 li.addEventListener("click", method) 
});

function function1() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(event.target.innerHMTL)
}
function function2() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(event.target.innerHTML)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however I need to explain again. I don't want to use forEach or any type of loop. That's when I placed an event on the menu wrapper #menu. 
When any LI is clicked I want to check if it has a submenu, if it does then I will add a class 'open'

Answer (score 0):

Your listener is registered on the top level menu but in your handler you are choosing to ignore events on the ULs. You only process events on LI. The LI itself does not have any UL associated with it and no event listeners are attached to the parent UL. So I think this is correct.

---

console.log(event.target.parentNode); will give you the UL(menu item) whose sub item you clicked.

---

This is a tricky problem to solve from scratch although I am sure it will be worth it. Here is just something to get started. There are a lot of problems you will need to address and build behaviour like toggling.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    menu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.target.children[0].className === 'submenu') {
            e.target.children[0].classList.add('open')
        } //ADD optional chaining here
    });
});
```

```css
.submenu {
    display: none;
}

.open {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            Option 1
            <ul class='submenu'>
                <li>Sub menu item 1</li>
                <li>Sub menu item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Option 2
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>Sub menu item 1</li>
                <li>Sub menu item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Option 3
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To be precise, 
When any LI is clicked I want to check if it has a submenu (ul) , if it does then I will add a class 'open'

Comment: Please see the edited answer. It does not include proper error checking but it should be good enough to get started with.

Comment: I think there will be multiple approaches to solving this type of problem but it is not such a trivial problem to solve. You can maybe use capture vs bubble OR check parents, siblings and descendants OR write CSS classes like I have done.

Comment: I think the easiest option will be to add classes on UL and LI to indicate whether they have sub-items or NOT. I have not thought this through completely but I think this would be the easiest method.

Comment: Also consider using an existing solution like a bootstrap accordion. But it would also be fun to build it from scratch idk. :D 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/